# Is it possible to detect changes in a javascript variable with a callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way of adding a listener or binding an event to a value instead of a html element?

So an event is triggered when a value changes instead of when you click a button, etc...

Hypothetical code:

```
var changingValue = 1;

$('button').on('click',function(){
    changingValue = changingValue + 1;
});

$(changingValue).on('change',function(){
    alert("event triggered, the new value is:" + this)
});
```

Comment: I don't understand, if you click on the button, the value is incremented. There is your change event.

Comment: `changingValue` should be a valid selector.

Comment: For example, i have an integer which is modified by several methods. Adding an event to the value being changed would be simpler and less code than adding the same event to several other methods. The duplicate questions don't have proven answers within the past 4 years which is why i asked again. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can if you use an object like so:

```
function Changing(initialValue, valueListener) {
    this._value = initialValue;
    this._listener = valueListener;
}
Object.defineProperties(Changing.prototype, {
    value: {
        get: function() {
            return this._value;
        },
        set: function(value) {
            this._value = value;
            this._listener(this._value);
        }
    }
});
```

Then you can do:

```
var changingValue = new Changing(1, function(value) {
    alert("event triggered, the new value is: " + value);
});

$('button').on('click',function(){
    changingValue.value += 1; // will alert "event triggered, the new value is: ..."
});
```

Comment: thanks, seems to do the trick. Any idea on browser compatibility?

Comment: It should work in all modern browsers, but there is a polyfill [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties#Polyfill) if you need it @SamJones